# Setting a column to be the same as a column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the current code I have.

```
UPDATE
    `ps_product_shop` 
SET
    `ps_product_shop`.`active` = `ps_product`.`active` 
FROM
    `ps_product_shop`
INNER JOIN
    `ps_product_shop` ON `ps_product_shop`.`id_product` = `ps_product`.`id_product`
```

I am trying to get the `active` column on the `ps_product_shop` table to get the values of active from the `ps_product` table. Essentially, if `ps_product`'s active column is '0', I need `ps_product_shop`'s active column to also be '0'. They share the `id_product` column.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently this should be

```
INNER JOIN `ps_product`
```

instead of

```
INNER JOIN `ps_product_shop`
```